# Issues with Apache HTTP Client and logging

Tags: java, apache, log4j, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-logging

In my Tapestry application, I need to do a GET request to a certain URL at some point. I do it like this (using Apache's HttpClient 4.2.1)

```
String scheme = getScheme();
String host = getHost();
int port = getPort();
String path = getPath();
String paramKey = getParamKey();
String paramValue = getParamValue();

URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
builder
    .setScheme(scheme)
    .setHost(host)
    .setPort(port)
    .setPath(path)
    .setParameter(paramKey, paramValue);

URI uri = builder.build();

HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(uri);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
```

When I deploy my WAR on Glassfish (3.1.2.2) and the code in question is executed, the following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: No suitable Log constructor [Ljava.lang.Class;@78aded17 for org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger (Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: No suitable Log constructor [Ljava.lang.Class;@78aded17 for org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger (Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category))
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:187)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:146)
```

I specify this in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And I checked and made sure the Class that is "not being found" is actually in WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.14.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have a classloader problem. Maybe another web application, that uses different log4j version, is loaded first. The classloader uses the first version of the class it finds. 
Try this:

- Remove all other applications from app server
- Check that you don't have another log4j in classpath of the server.

Try to install and start your application.

Comment: The only other logger is used in EJB and that is `java.util.logging.Logger`.

Comment: So you don't have any other web apps installed?

Comment: The only other is a servlet that's receiving that GET request and it's also using `java.util.logging.Logger`.

Comment: Can you check Glassfish lib directory, that there are not log4j jars?

Comment: In lib, no.
When I deploy my web app, even though I have no Log4J, glassfish still has some log4j stuff in `...glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\myWAR`

Comment: This is the problem. This jar is not compatible with yours. Try to remove it.

Comment: There are no jars in that folder, only some properties and config files

Comment: Thx for your effort, I ended up adding commons-logging.properties file instructing it to use `Jdk14Logger`.